# Buffer size in file I/O

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a small program to find the buffer size of an open file stream. After searching around a little bit, I found the __fbufsize() function. This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

void main() {
   FILE *f;
   int bufsize;

   f = fopen("test.txt","wb");
   if (f == NULL) {
      perror("fopen failed\n");
      return;
   }

   bufsize = __fbufsize(f);

   printf("The buffer size is %d\n",bufsize);

   return;
}
```

I get the buffer size as zero. I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening. Shouldn't the stream be buffered by default? I get a non-zero value if I use setvbuf with _IOFBF before calling fbufsize.

Comment: The macro `BUFSIZ` defined in `<stdio.h>` is the default buffer size.  There's no standard way to find the buffer size set by `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()`.  You need to identify the platform you're working on to allow useful commentary on `__fbufsize()` as a function (though it seems to be a GNU libc extension: [`__fbufsize()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/__fbufsize).

Comment: There's also a decent chance that until you use the file stream, the buffer size is not set.  Until then, you could change the size with `setvbuf()`, so the library probably doesn't set the buffer size until you try to use it.  Add `fputc('a', f);` after the `printf()`, and then test the size again; it probably isn't zero any more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that the correct return type for `main()` is `int`, not `void`.

This code compiles on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 derivative tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    size_t bufsize;

    f = fopen("test.txt", "wb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    bufsize = __fbufsize(f);
    printf("The buffer size is %zd\n", bufsize);

    putc('\n', f);
    bufsize = __fbufsize(f);
    printf("The buffer size is %zd\n", bufsize);

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces:

```
The buffer size is 0
The buffer size is 4096
```

As suggested in the comments, until you use the file stream, the buffer size is not set. Until then, you could change the size with `setvbuf()`, so the library doesn't set the buffer size until you try to use it.

The macro `BUFSIZ` defined in `<stdio.h>` is the default buffer size. There's no standard way to find the buffer size set by `setvbuf()`. You need to identify the platform you're working on to allow useful commentary on `__fbufsize()` as a function (though it seems to be a GNU libc extension: [`__fbufsize()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/__fbufsize)).

<sup>*There are numerous small improvements that should be made in the program, but they're not immediately germane.*</sup>

Comment: Interesting. I'm using a Linux machine as well(OpenSUSE). As a side question, is the value of BUFSIZ architecture specific? I get the value as 32768.

Comment: @npn: It varies by O/S for sure.  On Mac OS X (10.9.5 Mavericks), I get 1024 for BUFSIZE (a 64-bit compilation).  Classically, it was 512; these days, 1024 or 4096 are normal; 32768 is bigger than I've seen before, but not outrageously so.

Comment: On my machine (Linux), BUFSIZ doesn't seem to be the default buffer for fread and co. Explicitly setting the buffer size to BUFSIZ yields performance improvements. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

[`__fbufsize`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/__fbufsize) man page says:

> The `__fbufsize()` function returns the size of the buffer currently *used* by the given stream.

so I think this is buffer size used by the stream.